# Permissions when iterating over files in directory Unix TCSH scripting

Tags: unix, permissions, tcsh

I'm writing a script that will print the file names of every file in a subdirectory of my home directory.  My code is:

```
foreach file (`~/.garbage`)
     echo "$file"
end
```

When I try to run my script, I get the following error:

```
home/.garbage: Permission denied.
```

I've tried setting permissions to 755 for the .garbage directory and my script, but I can't get over this error.  Is there something I'm doing incorrectly?  It's a tcsh script.

Comment: the backticks are trying to invoke the program `~/.garbage`. You probably don't want to do that

Comment: I removed the ticks and it worked.  However now I have another issue.  The for loop only executes once, but there are 3 files in .garbage.  Is my directory formatting still incorrect?

Comment: `~/.garbage/*` is probably what you're looking for - there is no implicit search of a directory, so it's only using the name of the path. you probably took some code that previously did `ls ~/.garbage`, with the backticks, and this actually lists the contents of the directory

Comment: The asterisk prints the correct files with the path.  Is there a way to only print the file name of every file in .garbage?  Or do I need to do something with grep or sed?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `ls ~/.garbage`

or if you want each file on a separate line, `ls -1 ~/.garbage`

Answer (score 0):

backtic will try to execute whatever is inside them. You are getting this error since you are giving a directory name within backtic.

You can use `ls ~/.garbage` in backtics as mentioned by Mark or use `~/.garbage/*` in quotes and rely on the shell to expand the glob for you. If you want to get only the filename from a full path; use the `basename` command or some sed/awk magic